# paintComponent and super.paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I am new beginner of Java. Here below are two classes, one class extends `JComponent`, need to override the `paintComponent` method. Another class extends `JPanel`, also need to override the `paintComponent` method.

Why does `DrawingPanel` class (extend `JPanel`) need to call `super.paintComponent(g)` method, but the `CollageComponent` (extend `JComponent`) doesn't need to call `super.paintComponent(g)`?

I am so confused.

```
public class CollageComponent extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 300, 75);

        // inner green fill
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(300, 75, 100, 75);

    }
}


public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 300, 75);

        // inner green fill
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(300, 75, 100, 75);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say you need to always call it because `JPanel` extends `JComponent` and `JComponent` has a code you need to execute

Comment: but the CollageComponent extends JComponent also.

Answer (score 3):

By invoking super.paintComponent() you make sure that the default painting is done for that component and that LAF.

For a JPanel this basically means that the background is painted. The background may be different for each LAF.

For a JComponent, there really is no default painting since each class that extends JComponent is responsible for making sure the entire area of the component is painted.

In your simple example the code will work because a JComponent is transparent by default, which means the background is painted by the parent of your component. If the entire background is not painted, then there is the possibility of painting artifacts appearing in certain conditions (which I don't remember at this time).

However, if any LAF decides that they want to install default painting for the JComponent class, your code will never use that painting and your component will look strange in that LAF. So it is always safer to invoke super.paintComponent() when doing custom painting.

Edit:

The standard code for painting a background is:

```
if (isOpaque()) 
{
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

You would just add this code at the start of the paintComponent() method.

Comment: So, the original super class paintComponent does is painting the background?  I saw some codes online "extends JComponent", some "extends JPanel", and then add it to JFrame to display the drawing.  So, when should I extend JComponent, and when extend JPanel?

Comment: Well, all Swing components extend JComponent. So theoretically if you are creating a custom component you would extend JComponent. This means you would need to make the component opaque and implement your own painting code to paint the background every time before doing your own custom painting. A JPanel is meant to be a container to hold child components. But many people take advantage of the fact the a JPanel will paint the background automatically so they extend JPanel.

Comment: Thank you, it does make more sense for me now. I just look up the doc of paintComponent, it says "if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts."  What does this mean exactly? How can we know if component is opaque or not? What background color we use  to fill in? As my example code(extend JComponent), It doesn't have any code for paint the background. Sorry, My head got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As per the java -awt/swing api classes hirearchy, Component is the super class of Container.Therefore you need to call  constructors of Parent class(Component) from child classes(Container) using super keyword.

Comment: but the CollageComponent  extends JComponent, then CollageComponent is subclass, and JComponent is superclass, why this class doesn't need to use super keyword to override?

Comment: If CollageComponent is direct subclass of JComponent ,then it shuld need to use "super " keyword. Since  CollageComponent is not using "super" keyword, It may  be not direct sub class of  JComponent.Theremay be any intermmediate class between JComponent and CollageComponent.